# what is "function countably simple"?

Tags: measure-theory

i have this part of proof:

"We first consider the case $0<p<1$. Let $f=\sum_n a_n \chi_{E_n}$ be a simple function on X (take $f$ to be countably simple when $q=\infty$)"

what it means "take $f$ to be countably simple when $q=\infty$"

Thank you

Comment: There is not enough information in the question. Try to provide more context . How are $p$ and $q$ related?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy it is about Lorentz space $L^{(p,q)}$ in chapter of duality, here $0<p<1$ and $1<q\leq \infty$

Answer (score 0):

*(formally a comment, but perhaps this is sufficient for an answer)* This probably means that there are countably infinitely many values of $n$ involved. The number of distinct values of $a_n$ might not be infinite (for example, we could have $E_n = (\frac{1}{n+1}, \, \frac{1}{n})$ for each $n,$ with $a_n$ equal to $1$ or $2$ according as to whether $n$ is even or odd), and whether infinitely many distinct sets $E_n$ could be involved will depend on your specific definition of "simple function".